# Can i add extra fields?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using [Full Calendar.](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) Is it possible to add an extra field besides title in the events property ?

Comment: You would most likely have to break open the FullCalendar source code and modify it to add this capability.

Answer (score 1):

look at the last paragraph on this page:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

> In addition to the fields above, you
>   **may also include your own non-standard
>   fields** in each Event Object.
>   FullCalendar **will not modify or delete**
>   these fields. For example, developers
>   often include a description field for
>   use in callbacks such as eventRender.